# Replacing not null assertion operator "!!" to perform a mathematical expression

Tags: kotlin

In the following code, a check for null is done on two fields before subtracting them:

```
if ((testingStartTime != null) && (testingEndTime != null))
    summary.duration = testingEndTime!!.time - testingStartTime!!.time
```

Is it possible to remove the not-null assertion operator `!!` somehow in order to perform the subtraction? Even better would be a way to execute the above code without checking if both are not null in the if statement.

Comment: Do you want summary.duration to be null or have a default value if the null checks don't succeed?

Comment: Summary duration is never null.

Comment: I cover 3 possible cases in my answer, the bottom most is probably what you want for this use case, but it's debatable if it's any more readable/concise/elegant than what you already have.

Comment: What requires you to add the `!!`? It compiles fine for me in Android Studio without both `!!` if I have the `if` check.

Comment: Yea, once inside the if the compiler should have smart cast the 2 values to non nullable]

Comment: Yes, it compiles fine but some developers I have worked with get pissed when they see !! used in code (for what I consider invalid reasons).

Comment: @AndroidDev no you don't understand. I **dont** need the `!!` to compile the code. After `if(...)` this: `summary.duration = testingEndTime.time - testingStartTime.time` compiles fine.

Comment: @AndroidDev can you check out if my answer works for you?

Comment: @BartekLipinski Smart casting doesn't work if they are member properties.

Comment: @BartekLipinski you need `!!` if it's a `var` property and not a local variable.

Comment: Using `!!` is generally a bad idea, and the other developers are probably right to get pissed. It will lead to a `NPE`, there should be no need to use `!!`, you can use null checks and smart casts to avoid the use of `!!` in 99% of situations..

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I thought that as well (that's why I removed my comment about `vars`), but I realized that compiler seems to be able to figure local `vars` out as well (at least for kotlin 1.3.50). Member `vars` is a different story.

Comment: @BartekLipinski That's why I said "`var` **property**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
summary.duration = testingEndTime?.let { endTime ->
    testingStartTime?.let { startTime -> 
        endTime - startTime
    }
}
```

Which would work, but would assign `null` to `summary.duration` if either `testingEndTime` or `testingStartTime` are `null`. If you wanted a default value for when either of the dependant values is `null` then you could do:

```
summary.duration = testingEndTime?.let { endTime ->
    testingStartTime?.let { startTime -> 
        endTime - startTime
    }
} ?: 0
```

Or, if you don't want to change the value of `summary.duration` at all if either of the dependant values are null you can do:

```
summary.duration = if (testingEndTime != null && testingStartTime != null) {
    testingEndTime - testingStartTime
} else {
    summary.duration
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but that takes me from 2 lines of code to 5 lines. I guess there isn't a simpler way.

Comment: You just need the second `?: 0`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The reason being (for the OP) is that if the inner most expression evaluates to null, the outer most expression will fallback to the null coalescing `?:` operator and resolve to 0. I shall edit the answer

Answer (score 2):

It seems you declare testingStartTime and testingEndTime as mutable variables (var), so smart cast to not-nullable type can't be done. There are two idiomatic ways to fix your problem:

1. Declare testingStartTime and testingEndTime as immutable variables (val) (if possible)
2. Create two local immutable copies of these variables and work with them to make smart cast possible:

```
    val startTime = testingStartTime
    val endTime = testingEndTime
    if ((startTime != null) && (endTime != null))
        summary.duration = endTime.time - startTime.time
```

Comment: It will, unless these properties have custom getter or are declared open.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
fun main() {
    val x: Int? = null
    val y: Int? = 5

    val z = x-y
    print(z)

}

operator fun Int?.minus(x: Int?) : Int? {
    this ?: return null
    x ?: return null
    return this-x
}
```

I know it's too much of a code but it might be used at multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

If conciseness is important to you, you can combine scope functions that alternately use a receiver or a parameter so you don't have to name parameters. The readability might be questionable.

```
testingStartTime?.let { testingEndTime?.run { summary.duration = it.time - this.time } }
```

or

```
summary.duration = testingStartTime?.let { testingEndTime?.run { it.time - this.time } } 
    ?: summary.duration
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you could do this:

```
operator fun Double?.minus(other: Double?) = 
    if (this == null || other == null) null else this - other
```

And then use

```
summary.duration = (testingStartTime?.time - testingEndTime?.time)?: summary.duration
```

But wouldn't recommend overloading operators for primitives because it could make code illegible elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

You already check for nulls beforehand, so ideally the `!!` are not needed.

Kotlin would normally smart-cast these variables to non-null types, but this may be prevented because they are mutable class properties.
To fix this just assign them to local variables:

```java
    val start = testingStartTime
    val end = testingEndTime
    if (start != null && end != null) {
        summary.duration = start.time - end.time
    }
```

This has the same behaviour as your code, and yes uses more lines but looks cleaner in my opinion. If you really don't like to reassign the variables you could  also pass them as function paramaters for example.